Servidor Linux: Un nuevo puerto no funciona en https, solo funciona en http
He añadido el puerto 8000 a FirewallD. Pero cuando intento acceder a él, solo puedo hacerlo a través de http, pero necesito acceder a través de https. El dominio tiene un certificado SSL instalado.
He intentado:
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8000/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

Si escribo
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all

El puerto nuevo es listado (8000). Pero solo puedo acceder a él a través de http y no a través de https.
Lo estoy ejecutando en un servidor virtual montado sobre un Rocky Linux 8.6. Los otros servidores también tienen su certificado SSL y a todos se accede por https perfectamente.
¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto? Gracias.

hay que tener en cuenta una cosa para que el puerto lo tenga en https se deber usa el puerto 443 cuando se usa la certificación de seguridad
le dejor un video ya que es un tema largo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oN8l_DMSCkA
se deber ir a la siguiente archivo
   sudo nano  /etc/apache2/sites-available/defaulf-ssl.conf

y añadir la siguiente configuración
DocumentRoot es la ubicación de tu proyecto o archivo de la pagina
      <VirtualHost *:80>
      ..........
      ..........
      ..........
      </VirtualHost>

      <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName sitioweb1.com
        ServerAlias www.sitioweb1.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@sitioweb1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sitioweb1.com/public_html
     
        <Directory /var/www/sitioweb1.com/public_html>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        #Puede omitir esta linea si lo desea  
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitioweb1.com-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sitioweb1.com-access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

Reinicia Apache2
después de completa la configuración deber reinicia apache para toma la nueva configuración
 sudo apachectl restart

para obtener la certificación SSL deber tener el dominio que apunte a su pagina
https://certbot.eff.org/

El sistema operativo es Rocky Linux, Centos. Tengo instalado Apache y los cinco servidores virtuales tienen su certificado SSL (Let's Encrypt), no tengo la carpeta /etc/apache2. A todos los servidores se accede perfectamente por https:  ´https://dominio1.com´ etc.
